# Date Time from Multi ComboBoxes

Tags: c#

I am trying to combine a DateTime from a number of combo boxes that i have on a form.

From this image you can see how the combo boxes are laid out.
[image]

Wondering what is the best way to do this currently i have the following but am not sure that it is correct.

```
string startdate = cmbMonthYear.Text + "-" + cmbMonth.SelectedIndex.ToString()+ "-" + cmbDay.Text + " "+ "07:00";

DateTime StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What is the best way that i could go about this?

Comment: @AliRashidi or perhaps, easy questions are more easily answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would probably be to avoid the parse exact and make sure you have the most accurate representation of the date you want, preferably in integers. You'll want to set the `Value`-parts of the items in your comboboxes as well. You can probably do that in the code that adds the items to those comboboxes.

So you'll have something like:

```
// Check your input here
// ...
int day = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDay.SelectedValue);
int month = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMonth.SelectedValue); // No need to have text in SelectedValue, just integer
int year = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMonthYear.SelectedValue);

DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, 7, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you're sure about your input):

```
var date = new DateTime(int.Parse(cmbMonthYear.Text), cmbMonth.SelectedIndex, int.Parse(cmbDay.Text), 7, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.TryParse` method to also validate the input from the user. A good practice when sometimes you have textboxes instead of dropdownlists:

```
string startdate = cmbMonthYear.SelectedValue 
    + "-" + cmbMonth.SelectedValue
    + "-" + cmbDay.SelectedValue 
    + " 07:00";
DateTime StartDate;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(startdate, out StartDate){
  //invalid date, show a warning message (e.g. lblErrors.Text = "Start Date is not valid!";)
}else{
    //your date is parsed and valid :)
}
```